# Django use queryset method in annotation

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I'm working on a Django project with models for courses and sections.
I have made a custom aggregate method, 'stats' for sections which outputs a dictionary of values.
I would like to group my sections by instructor and annotate the respective stats to each group.

What I've tried so far:
I first get a Course and store it as `course`.

```
course.sections.values('instructor').annotate(section_count=Count('instructor'))
```

I would like to do something like: `course.sections.values('instructor').annotate(section_count=Count('instructor'), **stats)` , although that clearly doesn't work

This is my Section model:

```
class Section(models.Model):

    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, related_name='sections')

    instructor = models.CharField()
    average_GPA = models.DecimalField()
    As = models.DecimalField()
    Bs = models.DecimalField()
    Cs = models.DecimalField()
    Ds = models.DecimalField()
    Fs = models.DecimalField()
    withdrawals = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    class_size = models.PositiveIntegerField()

    objects = SectionQueryset.as_manager()
```

and this is the queryset code:

```
class SectionQueryset(models.QuerySet):
    def stats(self):
        def safe_round(val):
            return round(val, 2) if (type(val) is float) else val

        data = self.aggregate(
            GPA=Avg('average_GPA'),
            A=Avg('As'), B=Avg('Bs'),
            C=Avg('Cs'), D=Avg('Ds'), F=Avg('Fs'),
            students=Sum('class_size'),
            withdrawals=Sum('withdrawals'))

        return {key: safe_round(value) for key, value in data.items()}
```

Comment: Well your `**stats` contains something like `GPA=3, A=12,...`, so those are no *annotations*, but look more like filters.

Comment: on a Section object I can do section.GPA (= 3); on a SectionQueryset I can do queryset.stats()['GPA'] (= 3). I would like to annotate the groups similarly so I can access the same values, not to filter them. @WillemVanOnsem

Answer (score 0):

I was playing around with the annotations and realized I could store them as a dictionary:

```
stats_dict = {'average_GPA': Avg('average_GPA'),
        'As': Avg('As'), 'Bs': Avg('Bs'),
        'Cs': Avg('Cs'), 'Ds': Avg('Ds'), 'Fs': Avg('Fs'),
        'students': Sum('class_size'),
        'withdrawals': Sum('withdrawals')}
```

then I could use the `**` on it in the stats method in the Section Queryset: `data = self.aggregate(**stats_dict)`. This was equivalent to what I had before, however I then realized that I could instead do:

```
raw_stats = {'average_GPA': (Avg,'average_GPA'),
        'As': (Avg,'As'), 'Bs': (Avg,'Bs'),
        'Cs': (Avg,'Cs'), 'Ds': (Avg,'Ds'), 'Fs': (Avg,'Fs'),
        'students': (Sum,'class_size'),
        'withdrawals': (Sum,'withdrawals')}
```

and

```
stats_dict = {key: t[0](t[1]) for key, t in raw_stats.items()}
```

which allowed me to do:

```
to_annotate = {k: t[0]('sections__'+t[1]) for k, t in raw_stats.items()}
self.get_queryset().annotate(**to_annotate)
```

in my CourseModelManager.